# uWSGI signal propagation from Master to workers

Tags: python, signals, wsgi

Upon stop/restart of uWSGI, I want all the workers to do cleanup.
I use
`lazy-apps = False` because on the contrary I have db connection not properly set up in the workers (I am not using SQLAlchemy).

Master process is correctly receiving POSIX signals, although I am not able to intercept them to subsequently forward some signal to workers and thus forcing them to execute cleanup. I am able to register signals on workers' side and use them programmatically.

```
def myTrmHandler(signum):
   print("Catched SIGNAL %s" % (signum))
   backend.close()

@uwsgidecorators.postfork
def preload():
   '''
   preload code working OK in the workers in non-lazy mode
   it launches some background threads that are enabled in uwsgi configuration
   '''


def main():
   uwsgi.register_signal(2, "workers", myTrmHandler)
   uwsgi.register_signal(3, "workers", myTrmHandler)
   uwsgi.register_signal(15, "workers", myTrmHandler)
   app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The register_signal function is part of uwsgi's own signal API which has nothing to do with POSIX signals as stated in the [uwsgi docs:](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Signals.html)

> uWSGI Signals have *nothing* in common with UNIX/Posix signals (if you are looking for those, Managing the uWSGI server is your page).

[This page](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html) covers the utilization of POSIX signals by uwsgi processes, although it doesn't cover much about overriding signals from your app.

With python apps you can use the stdlib's `signal.signal(...)` to register your signal handlers, but you'll also need to add the `py-call-osafterfork` command line/config option in order for it to work ([docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=py-call-osafterfork#py-call-osafterfork))